# Sessions are going Inactive status

Tags: sql, multithreading, oracle, shell

I am running one sql query to fetch records from a table with multiple threads. Initially all the threads go in INACTIVE status and slowly it starts coming to ACTIVE status.

I have created HASH partition on my table based on the loc.

Also I have created an index over Item, loc columns.

```
select item || ',' || loc || ',' || stock_on_hand || ',' || on_order_qty || ',' ||  0 || ',' || in_transit_qtyAS csv
from makro_m_oplcom_stg
where loc = ${loc} and ITEM_INV_IND = 0;
```

When I run this query in my DB for one loc it takes only one sec to fetch the records but when I am running it from shell script in multi threaded mode I am facing the session going into INACTIVE mode.

This is my wrapper script. Inside this I am calling another shell script that has the above mentioned query.

```
while [ $thread -le $SLOTS ] do 
  sleep 1 
  LOG_MESSAGE "$pgm_name Started by batch_makro_oplcom_process for thread $thread out of $SLOTS by ${USER}"
 ( ksh $pgm_name.ksh $UP $SLOTS $thread 
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then 
    LOG_MESSAGE "$pgm_name failed for thread: $thread, check the $pgm_name error file." 
    exit 1 
  else
   LOG_MESSAGE "$pgm_name executed successfully for thread: $thread." fi ) 
  & let thread=thread+1 
done
```

Comment: Maybe you should provide some details of how you're implementing this multi-threading in the shell script. Also, how many CPUs does your server have?

Comment: For future reference, please **edit your question** to include clarifications or further information. Code is especially hard to read in a comment due to the lack of layout and poor formatting. Also you still haven't provided a complete set of code. Or indeed an explanation of why you've chosen to run this query in such a convoluted fashion, rather than just executing the whole thing as a single SQL statement. What do you hope to achieve?

Comment: *" I have created an index over Item, loc columns"* Do you mean  ITEM_INV_IND, LOC columns?